# getElementsByTagName for a specific form in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to write a generic javascript function (using jQuery) to acquire all input elements on a specific form - and return them as json.

```
function getFormDataAsJson(sFormId)
{
    // read input attributes from form; return as json

    var form = $(sFormId);
    if (form != null)
    {
        var inputs = $('input', form);
        var json = {};

        for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
        {
            var next = inputs[i];
            var key  = $(next).attr('id');
            var val  = $(next).val();

            if( val != null && key != null)
                json[key] = val;
        }

        return json;
    }
}
```

The error above is in the line:

```
var inputs = $('input', form);
```

Where form is a form object.  How can I get all input elements in the given form?

Comment: You might have to try `var form = $('#'+sFormId);` - ID selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("form").each(function(){
$(this).find(':input') //<-- Should return all input elements in that specific form.
});
```

or you can use

```
var form = $('#'+sFormId);
```

this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var form = $(sFormId);
```

to

```
var form = $('#'+sFormId);
```

*#* - [jQuery ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Also, alternatively if this is the only form you have, use :

```
var inputs = $('form :input');

$('form :input').each(function(){
     var key = this.id;
     var val = this.value;
     .....
});
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with jquery, so just wanted to ask if we can use       var form = document.getElementById("id") here?

Comment: Yes you can use `var form = document.getElementById(sFormId)` here to get the form object.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to use the selector below.use `#` selector

```
var form = $('#'+sFormId);


function getFormDataAsJson(sFormId)
{

var form = $('#'+sFormId);
if (form != null)
{
    var inputs = $('input', form);
    var json = {};

    for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
    {
        var next = inputs[i];
        var key  = $(next).attr('id');
        var val  = $(next).val();

        if( val != null && key != null)
            json[key] = val;
    }

    return json;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint from one of my recent projects.

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form"> 
    <input type='text' class='textInput' name="One"  id="one" value='0'>
    <input type='text' class='textInput' name="Two"  id="two" value='0'>
    <input type='text' class='textInput' name="Three"  id="three" value='0'>
    <input type='text' class='textInput' name="Four"  id="four" value='0'>
    <input type='text' class='textInput' name="Five"  id="five" value='0'>
    <input type='text' class='textInput' name="Six"  id="six" value='0'>
    <input type='text' class='textInput' name="Seven"  id="seven" value='0'>
    <input type='text' class='textInput' name="Eight"  id="eight" value='0'>
    <input type="submit" id='submit' value="Submit">
</form>
<p id='output'></p>
```

And JavaScrpipt:

```
$('form').submit(function(){    
    $('.textInput').each(function(){ 
        if($(this).val() != '0')
        {
            $('#output').text($('#output').text()+ ' ' + $(this).attr('name') + ':' + $(this).attr('value') );
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `$('#'+sFormId+' input')`  or with `form.find('input')`